# How can I monitor questions on multiple SE sites?

Tags: discussion

I'm interested in seeing any questions posted for a particular tag (in this case ArcObjects) on several different SE sites.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

This can be done using "Network Tag filters".

On the sidebar, click on "Network Tag filters" ...

[image]

Choose create a new filter ...

[image]

Specify what sites you are interested in, and save it ...

[image]

Now when you go to the page for the filter `http://stackexchange.com/filters/10616/arcobjects` you can see all questions for the tag.

[image]

Comment: Or I guess they could just monitor the url for my filter, http://stackexchange.com/filters/10616/arcobjects  which seems to be public.

Answer (score 2):

Another tool I have found useful is that of using the RSS feeds for the site (this can either be used with specific sites or with the network tag filter as Kirk already mentioned).

For my reader I have all recent questions in GIS and the Stats site sent. But for SO due to its higher traffic I have only [selected questions with specific tags](http://stackexchange.com/filters/4978/my-filter) to be sent to my reader. You can get a feed to any specific tag (or any combination of tags).

This isn't perfect for following questions (it only sends the initial subject and question), but it is definitely useful to at least be aware of newer questions.