# How on-topic are ArcObjects code questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

This question occurs to me because ArcObjects is a very GIS-centric beast, but it also has a strong basis in the nuts and bolts of programming and scripting.

While it can be assumed that any question about ArcObjects is inherently GIS-***related***, does that make it apropos to ask what amounts to an ArcObjects syntax question here?

I think having that information here could do a lot to increase foot traffic for beginning, intermediate, and advanced developers who would like to have all their eggs in one basket, but I am unsure as to whether this is considered the right basket.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We do not limit questions relating to QGIS or Python, and there is a need for all types of questions particularly if software-specific forums don't provide the needed answers.

I would suggest that question-posters try to be somewhat generic if at all possible, since, as you indicate, the question may be transferable to multiple platforms.

Also, note that the ArcObjects forum can generate as much traffice in a day as this site might see in a week.  It might be a matter of "exposure" or "me first" but I hope that is not the case.

Answer (score 8):

This question has been on my mind a lot lately.  While ArcObjects cuts across multiple SE sites (like Code Review and Stack Overflow) when it comes time to ask a question, I'm reluctant to post on one of those sites.  I figure my odds of getting a good answer are best here at GIS SE.  I don't like to cross post, so I just post once here.

Maybe if we blog about [cross-site monitoring](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/how-can-i-monitor-questions-on-multiple-se-sites), we can reach critical mass needed to encourage people to post questions on the most appropriate venue.

Answer (score 7):

I ask mostly development questions , but it's really really hard to get significant answer from other websites (such as Stack Overflow) because it is a **very broad domain - with just a few experts and experienced users.**

In short, this is the place to get THE answers.