# How do I follow a question?

Tags: feature-request, support

I am interested in this question:
[Reversing "combine" function on raster using R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49100/reversing-a-combine-function-on-a-raster)

I have seen this: [How can I monitor questions on multiple SE sites?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/how-can-i-monitor-questions-on-multiple-se-sites) which allows notification for keywords and some very neat filtering things.  I just want this question and not all the tags associated with this question.

I want to be notified if something happens in this question.  I know I can comment or answer and I will be notified.

If I upvote it I know it will appear on my feed, but since I know very little about the subject matter I don't know if it is a valid question.

Comment: I just figured out that this question referencing the other question in now in my feed.  Although it is a solution it isn't optimal.

Answer (score 4):

I **believe** marking a question as a favorite is the same as subscribing to it.

1. Mark a question as a favorite by clicking the "star" icon below the question's vote count.
2. Turn on email notifications for subscribed questions.

   - Click your username to open your profile
   - Click *prefs*
   - Check *allow email notifications when I subscribe to questions or tags*

Comment: This didn't seem to work.  Trying again for verification.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49205/estimated-population-around-a-point-qgis has been favorited.  Back in 3 hours

Comment: Has anyone else tested this?  I have favorited 4 questions have active markers (the highlighted number besides favorites) and I was not informed.  I have followed all steps.  I have also double checked that it isn't a per exchange thing and make the altercation to several of my accounts.